# How to lookup the current context in Nunjucks?

Tags: nunjucks

In Handlebars you can use `this` to look up the current context.

How do you do the same in Nunjucks?

For example, if you wanted to dump the entire context as a JSON string:

```
<script>window.__config__ = {{ this | dump | safe }};</script>
```

(But `this` doesn't seem to work in Nunjucks.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need `context` then you can add global function

```
var env = nunjucks.configure([...
...
env.addGlobal('getContext', function() { 
    return this.ctx;
})
```

And dump her result in template

```
{{ getContext() | dump| safe }}
```

Comment: `Template render error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` Note I didn't add anything to my template at all.

Comment: This error means that you try convert to string self-reference object: `var obj = {a: 10}; obj.b = obj; console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));` (filter dump is equals to `JSON.stringify`). You can define own filter e.g. `print` as `console.log(obj)` to avoid use `dump` (=`JSON.stringify`) for debug.

Comment: Bro I literally plugged in your code and got this error.

Comment: Your context contains self-reference object (it's a not usually), so when you call `dump` filter (equals to `JSON.stringify`) then you have error. To avoid error you must use other filter: e.g. you can write custom filter `print` to output context to console. http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#custom-filters

Comment: I'm not sure why. I didn't add anything to the template or the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you the variable `this` is available on a nunjucks template, but if it's another you wish to inspect you can use the `dump` method.

`{{ users | dump }}`

So that will print the json object, which looks really ugly if you have autoscape on.

`{{ users | dump | safe }}`

this will work just fine

ALTERNATIVELY:

```
env.addFilter('pprint', function(str, count) {
    return JSON.stringify(str, null, 4);
});
```

`{{ users | pprint | safe }}`